# Error message making a React app with vmsg

Tags: reactjs, heroku, npm

I am trying to create a react app on Heroku and I want to make use of vmsg (https://github.com/Kagami/vmsg).

I have set up a small app following these instructions:

```
https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack
Quick Start
```

I also ran:

```
npm install vmsg --save
```

I am now able to confirm that this file exists:

```
node_modules/vmsg/vmsg.wasm
```

Nevertheless inside index.js I hit a problem on this code (coming from the vmsg demo)):

```
  handleRecord = () => {
    vmsg.record({
      wasmURL: require("vmsg.wasm"),
      shimURL: "https://unpkg.com/wasm-polyfill.js@0.2.0/wasm-polyfill.js",
    }).then(record => {
      this.setState({record});
    });
  };
```

I get the error message:

```
remote:        ./src/index.js
remote:        Cannot find module: 'vmsg.wasm'. Make sure this package is installed.
remote:        
remote:        You can install this package by running: npm install vmsg.wasm.
```

I suppose I only need to put the proper import at the top of index.js.
Or modify this line:

```
wasmURL: require("vmsg.wasm"),
```

Though I am not sure and what I tried failed. Am I right? If YES, what is the right way to do it?

Or do I really need to run "npm install vmsg.wasm" as mentioned in the message?

.....
After giving it a try, this is actually not a valid solution; running:

```
npm install vmsg.wasm
```

is of no use.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the exact same question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68867992/react-where-to-place-a-static-file-pdf-other-to-be-able-to-reference-it

Comment: Actually no, I ended up by following a different path.