# Where to place a static file to be able to reference it?

Tags: reactjs, node-modules

[vmsg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vmsg) requires a URL link to a `.wasm` file that it requires in order to work. Their sample code (which does work) looks as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import vmsg from 'vmsg';

const test = new vmsg.Recorder({wasmURL: "https://unpkg.com/vmsg@0.3.0/vmsg.wasm"});
```

But I would like to have that file refer to a directory in my app rather than this external URL and I'm not certain:

1. Where I should place this file (`assets`/`public`/`node_modules` folder)?
2. What I would do to make this work (do I do an import or do I reference it directly somehow)?

I've tried placing the file in my assets folder and changing the line of code to many things along the lines of:

```
const test = new vmsg.Recorder({wasmURL: '../../assets/vmsg.wasm'});
```

But nothing seems to be working, which, after some reading, makes sense. But I'm still not sure what the right way to add a file like this should be instead.

Comment: Is this a CRA-created app (then see e.g. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/), or something else? Are you using Webpack (then file-loader would need to be configured for an import to give you the path)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I am using CRA with Craco. So, does that mean I should place it in the public folder and use something like `process.env.PUBLIC_URL`? Would that be right?

Comment: My understanding is Craco is used to _change_ the default configuration, so whether whatever those changes are would impact this functionality we can't tell you, but I'd be inclined to try that in your position.

Comment: Thank you, @jonrsharpe, I'm trying to use the `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` but getting another error. It does seem to be seeing the `wasm` file, though. Here's to hoping I'm on the right path. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen some people run into something like this specifically when trying to import photo assets.  One solution that I've found to work for that is to include .default at the end.

`const test = new vsmg.Recorder({wasmURL: require('../../assets/vmsg.wasm').default});`

Comment: That seems to work (as did @jonsharpe's idea of adding it to my public folder) - Now I've got the issue of loading the `.wasm` file in my local server, but at leats this is now working. Thank you!